# backlight trouble xubuntu lenovo ideapad 100

Tags: xubuntu, screen, lenovo, brightness, backlight

Brightness control is reversed. When I press the brightness control keys the increase button will make it dim and visa versa. The indicator for the brightness on display is also backwards, and before the screen times out instead of dimming a level it gets brighter and then dims back down when I move the mouse/touch-pad.Output of

```
    ls /sys/class/backlight/

    intel_backlight
```

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions to fix this. thank you.

Comment: edit your question and write output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and append the `i915.invert_brightness=1` kernel  paramenter to your kernel options at the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line.

For example, change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.invert_brightness=1"`

Update your bootloader configuration using `sudo update-grub2`and reboot.

It should solve your problem.